# Access and create .txt files from a PyInstaller one-file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10, pyinstaller

My code creates and access .txt files. Will this still work if I bundle it using PyInstaller as one file? I'm new to PyInstaller, so sorry if it's an obvious question.

Comment: Combining your source code into one fill will not restrict it from creating and accessing additional text files.

Comment: Yes, it will work. If you have initial `.txt` files, you will need to include them in your `Pinstaller` build.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work. Also, make sure that the `txt` files have static contents. if not, try to use some fronend tools to upload and use the file dynamically.